# WooCommerce show product related products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

In WooCommerce, for instance, my code below shows random products every time.
But in the WordPress admin panel, I selected under product all related products (4 of them) but my code still shows random products.

My code:

```
$related_products = wc_get_related_products(get_the_ID(), 4);
$related_products_count = count($related_products);
```

How I can display my added related products from the admin panel?

---

related products card:

```
<?php if($related_products_count > 0): ?>
    <section class="beige pt-5 pb-3">
        <div class="container-fluid px-0">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2 class="mb-4 all-title"><?php _e('Related products', 'rv'); ?></h2>
                    <article>
                        <div class="row">
                            <?php foreach($related_products as $related_product):
                            $post_object = get_post($related_product);
                            setup_postdata($GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object);
                                wc_get_template_part('single-product-card');
                            endforeach; ?>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Have you verified that `get_the_ID` returned a value? Are you using this inside the loop?

Comment: @CBroe code works but it shows 4 random products what are not even related with that product

Comment: You just repeated what you already stated inside the question. None of that is an answer to what I asked _you_ to clarify the issue.

Comment: I want show these related products what I selected from admin panel product edit page where is tab related products. I want show these products in my code.

Comment: It gives int(35) and that is current product id

Comment: Looks like you picked the wrong function then. https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/namespaces/default.html#function_wc_get_related_products: _“Get related products based on product category and tags.”_ - so this has nothing to do with getting _specific_ products you explicitly assigned as related, in the first place.

Comment: I think you actually want to use [`woocommerce_related_products`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/namespaces/default.html#function_woocommerce_related_products) here.

Comment: @CBroe `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_upsell_ids()`

Comment: Might be from an outdated version, I’d suggest  you do a bit of research what the equivalent in the current version might be then.

Comment: Got working with another code.

Answer (score 1):

This way is possible display related products by current product ID:

```
$product = new WC_Product(get_the_ID());
    $related_products = $product->get_upsells();
   if (!$related_products)
        return;
```